# How to Show Push Notification in Dialog when app is already opened and Notification comes?

Tags: android, push-notification

i wants to show only dialog when notification comes and app is already opened.
i do not wants to show notification on notificationbar if app is opened like divyabhaskar Android app

Comment: Please show some code for how you are currently receiving push notifications in your app.

Answer (score 1):

When notification comes write following code

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am
                    .getRunningTasks(1);
            Log.d("current task :", "CURRENT Activity ::"
                    + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClass().getSimpleName());
             ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
                        className = componentInfo.getClassName();
                        Log.v("", "class Name-" + className);

                        if (extras != null) {
                            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                    getPackageName())) {


                                    Log.v("", "inside app-");

                                    Intent broadcast = new Intent(ApplicationConstants.MY_BROADCAST);
                                    broadcast.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.BOOKING_ID, bookingId);
                                    broadcast.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.NOTIFICATION_TYPE, type);
                                    broadcast.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.MESSAGE, message);
                                    broadcast.putExtra(ApplicationConstants.CLASS_NAME, className);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(
                                broadcast);
                        Log.v("", "Sending broadcast....");
                    } else {
                        sendNotification(extras);
                   }
```

And register broadcast receiver in the activity where you want dialog.

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver,
            new IntentFilter(ApplicationConstants.MY_BROADCAST));
```

Receive Broadcast

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ApplicationConstants.MY_BROADCAST)) {
            //Log.v("", "inside on receiver-");

            showDialog(intent.getStringExtra(ApplicationConstants.MESSAGE));


        }
    }
};
```

In onStop Method unregister the broadcast

```
 @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (receiver != null) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```